# Remove subcategory and category with some rules from permalink

Tags: categories, permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

My current option for permalink is set to /%category%/%postname%/:

I have a category *'stati'* and parent category *'italian', 'german'*.
This parent category has some other parent category, for example:

- test.com/category/stati/italian/A/B/.../postname
- test.com/category/stati/german/A/B/.../postname

I need remove only this part **"category/stati/"**, the link should appear like this:

- test.com/italian/A/B/.../postname
- test.com/german/A/B/.../postname

But i need stick next rules:

1) if we come to category *"stati"* without subcategory ( test.com/category/stati/ ) i need remove only *"category"* - test.com/stati/

2) all my published posts has next link:

- test.com/stati/italian/postname,

i need to change link of this post if we stay in current subcategory for normal open this post.

- test.com/stati/italian/A/.../postname to -> test.com/italian/A/.../postname

I write simple code

```
// Remove category base
add_filter('category_link', 'no_category_parents',1000,2);

function no_category_parents($catlink, $category_id) {
    $category = &get_category( $category_id );
    if ( is_wp_error( $category ) )
        return $category;

    $category_nicename  = $category->slug;
    $category_parent    = get_category($category->parent)->slug;

    // If we have parent category and != 'stati' then add it to link and remove 'category'
    // test.com/category/stati/italian/A to -> test.com/italian/A

    // else this category is main category 'stati' left it and remove 'category'
    // test.com/category/stati to -> test.com/stati

    if ( $category_parent && 'stati' != $category_parent){

        $catlink = trailingslashit(get_option( 'home' )). trailingslashit( $category_parent ) . user_trailingslashit( $category_nicename, 'category' );

    }else{

        $catlink = trailingslashit(get_option( 'home' )) . user_trailingslashit( $category_nicename, 'category' );

    }

    return $catlink;
}
```

Part of my code works, but when i come to subcategory *'A'* (test.com/italian/A) i get 404 page. Maybe i need write some rewrite rules for parent category, but how this doing?

Thank you!